# Not creating arraylist Object Class from JSON in fragment (Android)

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

I have this fragment class that is showed when an element is selected in a navigation drawer:

```
public class RecibidosFragment extends Fragment {

    public ExpandListAdapterMensaje ExpAdapter;
    public ArrayList<ChildMensaje> ListChild=null;
    public ArrayList<Mensaje> ListMensajes=null;
    public ExpandableListView ExpandList;
    public ProgressDialog dialog;
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<ChildMensaje>> ListChildXXXXXXXXX = null;
    TextView tv;
    Context mContext;
    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static RecibidosFragment newInstance() {
        RecibidosFragment fragment = new RecibidosFragment();
        return fragment;
    }




    public RecibidosFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recibidos, container,
                false);

        mContext = container.getContext();

        tv = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(cargartodo());
        ExpandList=(ExpandableListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView2);

        ListMensajes = new ArrayList<Mensaje>();
        ListChild = new ArrayList<ChildMensaje>();
        ListChildXXXXXXXXX = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ChildMensaje>>();


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((menu_mensajes) activity).onSectionAttached(1);
    }
    public String cargartodo(){
        String arreglo = loadJSONFromFile();
        arreglo = "[" + arreglo+ "]";
        Mensaje men =null;
        ChildMensaje chmen=null;
        try {
            ArrayList<Mensaje> list = new ArrayList<Mensaje>();
            ArrayList<ChildMensaje> ch_list;


            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(arreglo);


            JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                if(jsonObject2.optString("success").equals("0")){
                    arreglo="No tiene mensajes recibidos.";


                }else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        arreglo="inside5";
                         JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                         men = new Mensaje(jsonObject.optString("asunto"), jsonObject.optString("origen"), jsonObject.optString("fecha"));
                         ListMensajes.add(men);
                         chmen = new ChildMensaje(jsonObject.optString("mensaje"));
                         ListChild.add(chmen);
                         ListChildXXXXXXXXX.add(ListChild);
                         ExpAdapter = new ExpandListAdapterMensaje(mContext, ListMensajes, ListChildXXXXXXXXX);
                         ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);

                    }}

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arreglo;
    }
    public String loadJSONFromFile() {

        String json = null;
        try {
//
           FileInputStream is = mContext.openFileInput("mensajes.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }

}
```

With :

```
public class ChildMensaje {

        public String mensaje;

        public ChildMensaje(){}
        public ChildMensaje(String mensaje){
            this.mensaje=mensaje;
        }


        public String getMensaje() {
            return mensaje;
        }

        public void setMensaje(String mensaje) {
            this.mensaje = mensaje;
        }

}


public class ExpandListAdapterMensaje extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    public Context context;
    public ArrayList<Mensaje> noticiasArrayList;
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<ChildMensaje>> ListChild;

    public ExpandListAdapterMensaje(Context context, ArrayList<Mensaje> noticiasArrayList,ArrayList<ArrayList<ChildMensaje>> ListChild) {
        this.context = context;
        this.noticiasArrayList = noticiasArrayList;
        this.ListChild=ListChild;
    }



    @Override
    public ChildMensaje getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return ListChild.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ChildMensaje child = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        ViewHolder holder=null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.mensaje=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mensaje);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.mensaje.setText(child.getMensaje());


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ListChild.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Mensaje getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return noticiasArrayList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return noticiasArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Mensaje not = (Mensaje) getGroup(groupPosition);
        ViewHolder holder= null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.asunto=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
            holder.fecha=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fecha);
            holder.origen=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dirigido);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.asunto.setText(not.getAsunto());
        holder.fecha.setText(not.getFecha());
        holder.origen.setText(not.getOrigen());


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView asunto, fecha,origen, mensaje;
    }


}

public class Mensaje {

    public String origen;
    public String asunto;

    public String getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(String fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public String getOrigen() {
        return origen;
    }

    public void setOrigen(String origen) {
        this.origen = origen;
    }

    String fecha;


    ArrayList<ChildMensaje> Items;

    public Mensaje() {
    }

    public Mensaje(String asunto, String origen, String fecha) {
        this.asunto = asunto;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.origen = origen;
    }

    public String getAsunto() {
        return asunto;
    }

    public void setAsunto(String asunto) {
        this.asunto = asunto;
    }

    public ArrayList<ChildMensaje> getItems() {
        return Items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<ChildMensaje> Items) {
        this.Items = Items;
    }
}
```

My issue just appear when I'm running the app. Just in the moment that I clicked the button for go to this fragment a message appear, The aplication must to be stopped and crashed.  I was just commenting the code line per line and I just know that the code is executed until that line ->

```
ListMensajes.add(men);
```

So, what I'm doing wrong ?? It has some solution ?? 
Thanks ;)

Comment: Just found the error.
tv.setText(cargartodo()); can handle the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ray's comment is right. It seems that the error occurs in your onCreateView() method.

```
tv.setText(cargartodo());
...
ListMensajes = new ArrayList<Mensaje>();
```

`cargartodo()` was called before the ListMensajes was initialized. In the `cargartodo()`  method, `ListMensajes.add()` will throw a NullPointerException.

Change `public ArrayList<Mensaje> ListMensajes=null` to `public ArrayList<Mensaje> ListMensajes= new ArrayList<Mensaje>` , it may work.